# How Can I Sync Active Directory User Profile Company Address with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, user-profile, active-directory

How can we Sync Active Directory User Profile Company Address with SharePoint 2013?
What is the mapping?

A VCard is:
ADR;WORK;PREF:;Main Office;12345 Here St.;MyCity;MyState;MyPostal;MyCountry

Is there a multi-value equivalent in AD or SharePoint?

Comment: Couple questions. Do you store the Company address for every user in AD? Is it a single field or split into many fields? How do you want to use it once you have it in SharePoint? What data types are you using in AD?

Comment: Hi Matthew, we are a police agency moving from GroupWise Email to Outlook and moving from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 this fall. We are cleaning our contact directory and applying business rules to keep them consistent. We're using AD to store all our contact information and sync it with Outlook and SharePoint. However, we can't seem to map address items such as "City"... it doesn't show up as a mapping choice in SharePoint. Ideally, we want the typical information you see on a business card.

Answer (score 1):

If the address is stored in Active Directory the attributes you are looking for are Named: AD

- Address: streetAddress
- City: l
- State: st

If you want to import these into the User Profile you can create a new User Profile Property for each AD property and then map the AD Attribute to the new User Profile Property in SharePoint.

Again, if you want to use these in Search Results you can create Managed Properties from your new User Profile Properties.